# Why isn't Task List showing up under Quick Navigation?

Tags: task-list

Why isn't my Task List showing up on the Quick Nav bar after I go to List Settings/List name, description and navigation/and selected yes under Display this list on the Quick Launch?

Answer (score 5):

Did you try this approach? go to site settings > Look and Feel > Navigation > Under 'Navigation Editing and sorting' > add an entry under current navigation.

Comment: That's a very good suggestion. I am not sure my administrator wants me to edit information from there. I will ask.